# Skin depth reference data for common materials

Tags: skin-effect

Is there any well-regarded publication that gives values for skin depths of common metals (Al alloys, brasses, other engineering alloys) in the Hz-to-MHz frequency range?  I am not an electrical engineer, perhaps there is someone here who knows such a source of reference data.

Comment: Isn't it just a function of resistivity and frequency? I don't see why you'd need to tabulate it.

Comment: OK, yes, resistivity and permabilities are tabulated.   Thanks.

Comment: Search on "skin depth calculator".  The ones I found are all in the microwave region.  This is fine if you're doing that work -- I was poking at some motor thing, so I was working in GHz/1000000 and getting answers in thousands of \$\mu\mathrm{m}\$, but I was able to translate.

Comment: Standard thickness copper foil --- 1 ounce per square foot---- of 1.4 mils or 35micron thickness, has skin frequency of about 5 MHz. Given the squareroot in the math, 20MHz gives TWO depths, and with each depth giving ONE NEPER (8.7dB), you can expect 2*8.7 = 17.4 dB attenuation.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Skin_depth_by_Zureks.png/350px-Skin_depth_by_Zureks.png

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing to do would seem to be to check Wikipedia. And doing so gives [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect)

Briefly, you can calculate the skin effect if you know the permittivity and permeability of the material, and both of those are well-known. For instance, [this page](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/permeability-d_1923.html) gives permeability for a wide range of metals (although for most metals the relative permiability is very close to 1). I'll assume that you have the basic Google skills to find the matching permittivity values.